# $.datepicker.regional['fr'] is undefined?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

WHen i upgraded jquery and jquery ui versions from 1.3.2 & 1.7.3 to 1.7.1 & 1.8.16 i recieved the error. can sombody help me how to recitfy this.

Jquery-1.7.1.js used
jquery-ui 1.8.16

Comment: Yes.................................

Comment: I saved the jquery libraries locally and calling them keeping jquery den jquery-ui den jquery autocomplete

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've already succeeded, but I was this error in production with debug=false in webconfig using Bundle Minification. For any reason that I don't know It doesn't do all bundle of the jQuery UI's script. I've separated the Datepicker script in other file javascript and will configure in the bundle config again. I don't know if this is your case,but with me It seems that worked. Your "datepiker" is loaded?